# Is there a way to get a list of keys in the google app engine blobstore?

Tags: google-app-engine, blobstore

My plan is to delete orphaned blobs by selecting one of these keys at random and checking for a reference to it in the datastore (and repeating once every ten seconds or so). Is there a way to get that list?

Comment: Have you tried using keys_only? something like: q = Person.all(keys_only=True)

Answer (score 3):

The method you're looking for is the queryBlobInfos() method on BlobInfoFactory.  It will give you all the stored blobs, and you can go through and remove the orphans.  No idea why this isn't on the BlobstoreService.
  https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/blobstore/BlobInfoFactory#queryBlobInfos()

Answer (score 1):

When you have a reference in the datastore you can get the file_name and delete the orphans.

```
    blob_key = # you have stored
    blob_info = blobstore.BlobInfo.get(blob_key)
    blobs = blobstore.BlobInfo.gql("WHERE filename = '%s'" %(blob_info.filename))                            
    for blob in blobs :
        if blob.key() != blob_key :    # do not delete the referenced one 
            blob.delete()
```

Ofcourse you can also use gql to query all blobs and compare it to your reference.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Goose answer here is the way I cleanup all my dev mess after experimentations:

```
    private BlobInfoFactory blobInfoFactory = new BlobInfoFactory();

private void deleteAllBlobs() {
    Iterator<BlobInfo> blobsIterator = blobInfoFactory.queryBlobInfos();
    while (blobsIterator.hasNext()) {
        BlobInfo blobInfo = (BlobInfo) blobsIterator.next();
        LOG.info("Removing blob " + blobInfo.getFilename());
        blobstoreService.delete(blobInfo.getBlobKey());
    }
}
```